# Angular : How to test a NgBootstrap modal component

Tags: angular, angular5, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test NgBoostrap modal component ,I'm using an NgbModal; it's wrapped in  and renders by calling the NgModal's open method which is passed the modal's content via a template reference variable. And in test I can't access the model's content so, I'm unable to to open the modal. How to test this modal close and dismiss function.

```
<button (click)="openDialog(formContent);" id="btnOpen"></button>
```

Here is my ng-template code:

```
<ng-template #formContent let-c ="close" let-d="dismiss">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross 
click')">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" 
formControlName="radioBasicOption">
<label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="option1" required>
</label>
<label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
<input ngbButton type="radio" value="option2" required>
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  isActive &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="isactive" />
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-success" id="okButton" type="submit" 
(click)="c(form.value)" [disabled]="form.controls['radioBasic'].invalid">
Save
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="d('Close 
clicked')">
Close
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

controller.js:

```
 openDialog(content: any) {
  console.log('success');
 }, (reason) => {
  console.log('error');
 });
```

How can I write unit test case for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437135/how-to-do-jasmine-unit-test-case-for-angular-6-bootstrap-4-modal

Answer (score -1):

In your `component.ts` file you have to use some thing like this...

```
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, 
                private modalRef: NgbModalRef) {}

    ngOnInit() { }

    openDialog(content: any) {  // To open modal 
       this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true, size: 'lg' });
    }

    closeModal() {  // To manually close modal
       this.modalRef.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: @jayraj-  i have done same in component, my question is how can i write unit test case for the functionality of modal (close & dismiss)