# How to do jasmine unit test case for angular 6 bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine, ng-bootstrap

**html**

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>   
<h1>Modal content inside this ng-template #content </h1>  
</ng-template>
```

Button to open model

```
<button  (click)="open(content)" > Open modal </button>
```

**In ts file**

```
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
constructor(  public modalService: NgbModal) { }

open(content) {  
          this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', size: 'lg' }).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
          }, (reason) => {
            this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
          });
           }
```

How to do a jasmine test case for this **open** function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I've tested it in the past...

Assuming the component TS file looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private _modalService: NgbModal) {}

  public openModal(content): void {
    this._modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' }).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
       this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    return  `with: ${reason}`;
  }
}
```

You can use the following test class which will test these scenarios:

1. `this._modalService.open` is called with the correct parameters
2. When the modal is closed, `closeResult` is updated correctly
3. When the modal is dimissed, `closeResult` is updated correctly

The test class looks like this:

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgbModal, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

// Mock class for NgbModalRef
export class MockNgbModalRef {
  result: Promise<any> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('x'));
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  let fixtureUnderTest: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let componentUnderTest: MyComponent;
  let modalService: NgbModal;
  let mockModalRef: MockNgbModalRef = new MockNgbModalRef();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot()
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixtureUnderTest = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    componentUnderTest = fixtureUnderTest.componentInstance;
    modalService = TestBed.get(NgbModal);
  }));

  it('should open modal', () => {
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);
    componentUnderTest.openModal('<xxxx>');
    expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('<xxxx>', { size: 'lg' });
  });

  // Needs to be async as modal result returned in a promise
  it('should update closeResult when modal closed', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);

    componentUnderTest.openModal('<xxxx>');
    tick();
    expect(componentUnderTest.closeResult).toBe('Closed with: x');
  }));

  // Needs to be async as modal result returned in a promise
  it('should update closeResult when modal dismissed', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(mockModalRef);
    // Override the result returned from the modal so we can test what happens when the modal is dismissed
    mockModalRef.result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('y'));

    componentUnderTest.openModal('<xxxx>');
    tick();
    expect(componentUnderTest.closeResult).toBe('Dismissed with: y');
  }));

});
```

Comment: Hi @ian-a  i worked for me , the second test case is failing other 2 are working. 
but some times an error is throwing  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined thrown" . If any idea about this please help

Comment: Do you have a `code` variable anywhere in your component TS file?

Comment: :) thanks for the clue. yes there was & i checked for undefined it worked .

Comment: @IanA how would I do this same test, except instead of calling openModal method on componentUnderTest, I would actually query the DOM for a button that when clicked opens the modal?

Comment: @Bmoe assuming you have a button with the ID `open-modal-button` that calls the a function which opens the modal, you should be able to say `fixtureUnderTest.debugElement.query(By.css('#open-modal-button')).nativeElement.click();` to trigger opening the modal by clicking the button. The variable `fixtureUnderTest` would be an instance of `ComponentFixture<MyComponent>` which can be instantiated in the `beforeEach` of the test class setup

Comment: I'm not a big fan of these spys.  Why can't we do a test where we actually confirm the subsequent modal window opens correctly?  IE "user clicks button, wait a bit, modal should exist in DOM".  In my tests the modal HTML element never opens